# class needs to be abstract since method in trait is not defined error

Tags: scala, class, object, inheritance, traits

Let's say we have a base class(trait) with two methods(same name, different parameters, and not implemtented):

```
trait Base {
    def compute(arg1:type1, arg2:type2): returnType
    def compute(arg1:type1, arg2:type2, arg3:type3): returnType
}
```

And we have some classes inherit from Base. Suppose they are A, B, C. A and B implement "compute" with two args, while C implements "compute" with three args.

```
class A  extends Base {
    def compute(arg1:type1, arg2:type2): returnType = {
        //detailed implementations
    }
}

class B  extends Base {
    def compute(arg1:type1, arg2:type2): returnType = {
        //detailed implementations
    }
}

class C  extends Base {
    def compute(arg1:type1, arg2:type2, arg3:type3): returnType = {
        //detailed implementations
    }
}
```

Now, I have a set of these objects `objs` and I want to automatically choose which version of "compute" to use:

```
val name = objs.map{ x =>
    val name = x.getClass.getSimpleName
    name match {
        case "C": x.compute(arg1, arg2, arg3)
        case _: x.compute(arg1, arg2)
    }
}
```

However, it compiles error:

`class A(B the same) needs to be abstract, since method compute in trait Base of type (three parameters) is not defined`

I'm confused at this error. Is that because all methods in `Base` must be implemented in its child classes(A,B,C)?

Is there any elegant fixes without editing class A and class B(because class C is most recently designed, and it's `compute` must add one more parameter, so I designed one more function above)?

Comment: You've defined interface (trait) Base and three non-abstract implementations of it. So, they must implement all methods of interface (trait)

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan is correct.  Might making the third argument an `Option` make things easier?

Comment: If "third argument an Option", will class A and class B have to change?

Comment: @user3162587 Yes, the function signature for all three would be the same, where the third argument is `arg3: Option[type3]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with @Mik378.  But if you are in the process of migrating from the 2 args version to the 3 args version, you can:

```
trait Base {
  // Mark this as deprecated
  // No default implementation here because otherwise, A & B would need to 
  // be modified to add the 'override' keyword
  @deprecated
  def compute(arg1:type1, arg2:type2): returnType

  // Provide a default implementation for old implementations e.g. A / B
  def compute(arg1:type1, arg2:type2, arg3:type3): returnType =
    compute(arg1, arg2)
}

// Convenience base class for new implementations e.g. C
abstract class NewBase extends Base {
  override def compute(arg1: type1, arg2: type2): returnType =
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException
}

class A  extends Base {
  def compute(arg1:type1, arg2:type2): returnType = {
    //detailed implementations
  }
}

class B  extends Base {
  def compute(arg1:type1, arg2:type2): returnType = {
    //detailed implementations
  }
}

// All new implementations extend 'NewBase' instead of 'Base'
class C  extends NewBase {
  override def compute(arg1:type1, arg2:type2, arg3:type3): returnType = {
    //detailed implementations
  }
}
```

And now, you can just use the 3-args version for old & new objs,

```
val name = objs.map(_.compute(arg1, arg2, arg3))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really what I need!

Answer (score 1):

You'll either need to define `compute(arg1:type1, arg2:type2, arg3:type3)` in `A` and `B` and defined `compute(arg1:type1, arg2:type2)` in `C` or you can provide a default, no-op implementation in your trait

```
trait Base {
    def compute(arg1:type1, arg2:type2) {}
    def compute(arg1:type1, arg2:type2, arg3:type3) {}
}
```

I'd also recommend defining the return type explicitly in `Base`

*Edit*

A full (simplified) working example using case classes:

```
trait Base {
  def compute(arg1: Int, arg2: Int): Int = 0
  def compute(arg1: Int, arg2: Int, arg3: Int): Int = 0
}

case class A() extends Base {
  override def compute(arg1: Int, arg2: Int): Int = arg1 + arg2
}

case class B() extends Base {
  override def compute(arg1: Int, arg2: Int): Int = arg1 - arg2
}

case class C() extends Base {
  override def compute(arg1: Int, arg2: Int, arg3: Int): Int = arg1 + arg2 - arg3
}

case class D(arg1: Int, arg2: Int, arg3: Int, objs: Seq[Base]) {
  val computed = objs map (_ match {
    case x: C    => x.compute(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    case x: Base => x.compute(arg1, arg2)
  })
}
```

Comment: The first option will work, but I don't want to change class A and class B. The second option still occurs the same error.

Comment: Sorry for missing the return type. Actually, I have return type in my original code. I have found that, with return type, the second option will not work.

Comment: I've updated my response.  A fundamental flaw in your example is the case statement in your map function.  You are using `:` instead of `=>` when defining the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

### Have you heard about *interface segregation principle*?

> The interface-segregation principle (ISP) states that no client should
>   be forced to depend on methods it does not use.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) ISP splits
>   interfaces that are very large into smaller and more specific ones so
>   that clients will only have to know about the methods that are of
>   interest to them. Such shrunken interfaces are also called role
>   interfaces.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)

Traits are in some ways similar to those named "interfaces".

Basically, you have to split `Base` trait.
Traits represent modules in Scala and it's a good practice to keep them small so that we increase their ability to be combined and get larger abstractions.

You would end up with two Traits:
(I merely altered the naming to be clearer)

```
trait Computation {
  def compute(arg1:Int, arg2:Int): Unit
}

trait SpecificComputation {
  def compute(arg1:Int, arg2:Int, arg3:Int)
}

class A extends Computation {
  def compute(arg1:Int, arg2:Int) = {
    //detailed implementations
  }
}

class B  extends Computation {
  def compute(arg1:Int, arg2:Int) = {
    //detailed implementations
  }
}

class C extends SpecificComputation {
  def compute(arg1:Int, arg2:Int, arg3:Int) = {
    //detailed implementations
  }
}
```

If you want a `class D` that should know about those two `compute` method variants, you write:

```
class D extends SpecificComputation with Computation {

      def compute(arg1:Int, arg2:Int) = {
        //detailed implementations
      }

      def compute(arg1:Int, arg2:Int, arg3:Int) = {
        //detailed implementations
      }
}
```